# Confusion in encryption of a file

Tags: python

I am trying to ecrypt a text file using one's complement operator.

Code is given below:

```
import sys
def encrypt():
    try:
        fs=open('SOURCE.txt','r')               #normal file
        ft=open('TARGET.txt','w')               #encrypted file
    except:
        print "File opening error!"
        sys.exit(1)
    while True:
        ch=fs.read(1)
        if not ch:
            break
        ft.write((ord(ch))^65535)
    fs.close()
    ft.close()
encrypt()

TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

Why,it is giving that error? Any solution for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the full traceback, you will see that the error is right here

```
ft.write((ord(ch))^65535)
```

`write` expects a character buffer object (such as a string) but you are passing an `int`.

But you can't just use `str()` as that will convert the byte to ASCII. To write it as binary data, use `bytearray()`.

```
ft.write(bytearray([ord(ch)^0xff]))
```